# C++ converting string containing non human readable data to 200 double

Tags: c++

I have a string whose length is 1600 and I know that it contains 200 `double`. When I print out the string I get the following :`Y���Vz'@��y'@��!U�}'@�-...`

I would like to convert this string to a vector containing the 200 doubles.

Here is the code I tried (`blobString` is a string 1600 characters long):

```
string first_eight = blobString.substr(0, sizeof(double)); // I get the first 8 values of the string which should represent the first double

double double_value1

memcpy(&double_value1, &first_eight, sizeof(double)); // First thing I tried

double* double_value2 = (double*)first_eight.c_str();  // Second thing I tried

cout << double_value1 << endl;
cout << double_value2 << endl;
```

This outputs the following:

```
6.95285e-310
0x7ffd9b93e320
```

--- Edit solution---

The second method works all I had to do was look to where double_value1 was pointing.

```
cout << *double_value2 << endl;
```

Comment: The 1st method looks correct (if the bytes are the same endian) how do you know the values are correct/incorrect?  Note that `double_value2` is a pointer not a double value and outputting `e320` does not match your program code.

Comment: In `cout << double_value2 << endl;` You are just printing the value of a **pointer**, not what is **pointed to**.

Comment: @RichardCritten Does it? `first_eight` is a `std::string`, not an array.

Comment: Thanks for your help, It was my dumb mistake of not realizing that it was a pointer .... now the second solution works fine :) still have a lot to learn

Comment: Read the question a bit better. `std::string` isn't trivially copy-able, so `memcpy` on the the address of a `string` won't work. Who knows how the sting is implemented. Could be a pointer and a count in there. Maybe a couple pointers and a buffer for short string optimization, Crom only knows what `memcpy` will actually wind up copying. `memcpy`ing `std::string::data` can work, assuming endian and the encoding used by the source and the current machine match.

Comment: Word of warning - if you're not using the same machine to read/write the data, you may end up with endian issues (where the order of the bits changes).

Comment: Whatever lead you to have a string of pointers, it's almost certainly wrong in some fundamental way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that might get you closer to what you need. Bear in mind that unless the numbers in your blob are in the exact format that your particular C++ compiler expects, this isn't going to work like you expect. In my example I'm building up the buffer of doubles myself.

Let's start with our array of doubles.

```
double doubles[] = { 0.1, 5.0, 0.7, 8.6 };
```

Now I'll build an `std::string` that should look like your blob. Notice that I can't simply initialize a string with a `(char *)` that points to the base of my list of doubles, as it will stop when it hits the first zero byte!

```
std::string double_buf_str;
double_buf_str.append((char *)doubles, 4 * sizeof(double));

// A quick sanity check, should be 32
std::cout << "Length of double_buf_str " 
          << double_buf_str.length()
          << std::endl;
```

Now I'll reinterpret the `c_str()` pointer as a `(double *)` and iterate through the four doubles.

```
for (auto i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    std::cout << ((double*)double_buf_str.c_str())[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Depending on your circumstances you might consider using a `std::vector<uint8_t>` for your blob, instead of an `std::string`. C++11 gives you a `data()` function that would be the equivalent of `c_str()` here. Turning your blob directly into a vector of *doubles* would give you something even easier to work with--but to get there you'd potentially have to get dirty with a `resize` followed by a `memcpy` directly into the internal array.

I'll give you an example for completeness. Note that this is *of course* not how you would normally initialize a vector of doubles...I'm imagining that my `double_blob` is just a pointer to a blob containing a known number of doubles in the correct format.

```
const int count = 200; // 200 doubles incoming
std::vector<double> double_vec;
double_vec.resize(count); 
memcpy(double_vec.data(), double_blob, sizeof(double) * count);

for (double& d : double_vec) {
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
}
```

@Mooning Duck brought up the great point that the result of `c_str()` is not necessarily aligned to an appropriate boundary--which is another good reason not to use `std::string` as a general purpose blob (or at least don't interpret the internals until they are copied somewhere that guarantees a valid alignment for the type you are interested in). The impact of trying to read a double from a non-aligned location in memory will vary depending on architecture, giving you a portability concern. In x86-based machines there will only be a *performance* impact AFAIK as it will read across alignment boundaries and assemble the double correctly (you can test this on a x86 machine by writing then reading back a double from successive locations in a buffer with an increasing 1-byte offset--it'll just work). In other architectures you'll get a fault.

The `std::vector<double>` solution will not suffer from this issue due to guarantees about the alignment of newed memory built into the standard.

Comment: I think `(double*)double_buf_str.c_str()` isn't _technically_ safe, aren't there alignment requirements?

Comment: Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding was that newed or malloc'd blocks of memory were guaranteed to be aligned based on the requirements of the largest standard type--e.g. long long. But I'll research that tomorrow and see for sure.

Comment: (A) you're right, I overlooked that (B) There's no guarantee that `.c_str()` is aligned. GCC put metadata at the start of the allocation before the string characters.

Comment: I'll check out out for sure, but I'd be really surprised if the metadata struct + string was packed to an alignment smaller than 8 bytes. (Of course whether or not that is guaranteed by the standard is another matter.)